# force jenkins slave to use internal host?

Tags: jenkins

How do i force a jenkins slave to connect to an internal host name via its run command for the actual JNLP connection?

More info below on the actual problem (with fake domains)

---

- Master public address : https://jenkins.fakehost.com
- Master internal address : http://jenkins.fakehost.internal
- Environment: Docker containers

Command ran:

```
java -jar slave.jar \
     -jnlpUrl http://jenkins.fakehost.internal/computer/SLAVE_NAME/slave-agent.jnlp \
     -secret SECRET;
```

Output ....

```
Sep 04, 2016 5:21:38 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
9/5/2016 1:21:38 AMINFO: Locating server among [https://jenkins.fakehost.com/, http://jenkins-internal.fakehost.com/]
9/5/2016 1:21:38 AMSep 04, 2016 5:21:38 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
9/5/2016 1:21:38 AMINFO: Handshaking
9/5/2016 1:21:38 AMSep 04, 2016 5:21:38 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
9/5/2016 1:21:38 AMINFO: Connecting to jenkins.fakehost.com:50000
```

Which subsequently led to.

```
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:369)
9/5/2016 1:23:56 AM at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:267)
```

The problem is, despite providing an internal host name, the slave agent, attempts to check for its public host name. And as its https port, but not 50k internal port is valid. Attempts hopelessly to a port it cannot reach.

I been trying to over-ride the command to force it to use the internal hostname, which the slave supports

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the advanced configuration tab for your JNLP slave, there's an option `Tunnel connection through`.

Entering `jenkins.fakehost.internal:` should fix the issue.

Comment: For the tunnel connection : is that for the http port, or the jnlp port (50,000)?

Comment: That is for the JNLP connection. The http(s) part works already fine on your side (that passes only the JNLP connection details). What fails is the JNLP connection establishment that starts after that. By configuring the tunnel, you can override Jenkins' idea on where it is running (ie, the JNLP connection information that's passed in the initial HTTP part).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following, to block the public host before the slave.jar

```
echo "127.0.0.1 jenkins.fakehost.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

This will force the slave to connect via the alternative given hostname

In the end, i modified the docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/picoded/jenkins-build-slave/)
to allow me to run a "command" before jenkins startup.

Note: Question left open, for a less hacky answer =)